# Generate clover report on several modules

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, code-coverage, clover

I have a pipeline Jenkins build for a gradle-project with several (5) modules.

Each module contains configured `clover` tasks, so that after calling `cloverGenerateReport`, I have several sets of results placed in:

- module1/build/reports/clover
- module2/build/reports/clover
- etc.

But as far as I can see [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/clover/), `cloverReportDir` supports only one value. 
Each report folder seem to contain the same-named files so I cannot just copy all of them to a common folder.
What is the way to generate clover report for several reports in one build?

Current clover step configuration:

```
  steps {
            sh "./gradlew clean cloverGenerateReport"
            step([
                    $class              : 'CloverPublisher',
                    cloverReportDir     : 'server/build/reports/clover',
                    cloverReportFileName: 'clover.xml',
                    healthyTarget       : [methodCoverage: 70, conditionalCoverage: 80, statementCoverage: 80], // optional, default is: method=70, conditional=80, statement=80
                    unhealthyTarget     : [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50], // optional, default is none
                    failingTarget       : [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]     // optional, default is none
            ])
        }
```

Comment: Per https://openclover.org/doc/manual/4.2.0/maven--configuring-reports.html, there are `aggregate` and `merge` goals.

Comment: This is a maven configuration, but I found similar task in gradle plugin. The question is still how to set the location of final aggregated report